# create link for any element in categories Highcharts widget

Tags: highcharts, yii2, href

I used Highcharts widget in view yii2 project.I want to create  URLs for category labels on bar chart (Highcharts widget), in my code can use bold tag and labels are bold but when add href tag I have not any link.

how can create href link in xAxis categories?

```
 <?php
                    $x = array("a", "b", "c");
                    $y = array_values(array(4, 2, 6));
                    echo Highcharts::widget([
                        'options' => [
                            'chart' => [
                                'type' => 'column',
                                'zoomType' => 'x',
                            ],
                            'title' => [
                                'text' => 'Project chart',
                            ],
                            'xAxis' => [
                                'categories' => $x, 
                                  'labels' => [
    'formatter' => new JsExpression('function(){ return "<a href=hghgh><b>"+this.value+" bgbgbg</b></a>"; }')
    ],
                                  'useHTML'=> 'true'

                            ],
                            'yAxis' => [
                                'title' => [
                                    'text' => 'Count',
                                ],
                            ],

                            'series' => [
                                [
                                    'type' => 'column',
                                    'name' => 'p1',
                                    'data' => $y,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]);
                    ?>
```

[image: titles are bold but have not link]

Comment: I don't know the yii2, but from Highcharts site it looks like the useHTML for xAxis labels needs to be changed to true to enable using HTML attributes. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few Things you need to look at

1. You are using `options` option whereas you should use the `clientOptions` *(if you are using this widget i suppose https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget)*
2. You are using the `useHtml` in the wrong place it should be under `labels` option and not the `categories`, also you should pass a `boolean` to the `useHtml` means without the quotes `true` should be passed.

Your complete code should look like below

```
<?php

use yii\web\JsExpression;
use dosamigos\highcharts\HighCharts;

$x = array("a", "b", "c");
$y = array_values(array(4, 2, 6));

echo HighCharts::widget([
    'clientOptions' => [
        'chart' => [
            'type' => 'column',
            'zoomType' => 'x',
        ],
        'title' => [
            'text' => 'Project chart',
        ],
        'xAxis' => [
            'categories' => $x,
            'labels' => [
                'formatter' => new JsExpression('function(){ return "<a href=hghgh><b>"+this.value+" bgbgbg</b></a>"; }'),
                'useHTML' => true,
            ],
        ],
        'yAxis' => [
            'title' => [
                'text' => 'Count',
            ],
        ],

        'series' => [
            [
                'type' => 'column',
                'name' => 'p1',
                'data' => $y,
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: tanks a lot , your response was very perfect.